# ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE - Not updating

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, duplicates

I am having an issue with my code not updating an existing computers data. If i remove the ON Duplicate section the code works fine and adds the data.  i have made computer my unique key in my xampp data base. any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php

$receive = htmlspecialchars($_POST['time']);
list($length, $status, $computer) = split(":", $receive, 3);     
include('connection.php');


mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT INTO screen(computer,status,length)
VALUES('$computer','$status','$length')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
status=$status, length=$length");

?>
```

Comment: You forgot to qoute your update values -> `UPDATE status='$status', length='$length'`

Comment: Sean - You are my hero. Thanks for the fix

Answer (score 0):

A better pattern for creating a SQL statement which mitigates some common SQL Injection vulnerabilities. Also note that the special `VALUES()` function can be used to reference the values that would have been inserted for a column, if the insert had succeeded.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO screen(computer,status,length)
VALUES('" 
. mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$computer)
. "','"
. mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$status)
. "','" 
. mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$length)
. "')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
status=VALUES(status), length=VALUES(length)";

mysqli_query($dbc,$sql);
```